# Sanitize input before executing at server in php

Tags: php, javascript

I want to let user input two variable, Name and Password in a form. I want to disable any XSS or script insert in the input values. I have the following code in the form method:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="checkpw.php">
Your Name:
<table>
  <tr><td><input class="text" name="name" onBlur="capitalize(this);" maxlength=12 type="text" /></td></tr>
</table> 
Password:
<table>
  <tr><td><input class="text" name="passwd" maxlength=8 type="password" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td align="center"><br/>
     <input class="text" type="submit" name="submitbt" value="Login" />
  </td></tr>
</table>
```

and the following checkpw.php:

```
<?php

// Clean up the input values 
$post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, array(
    'name' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'pw' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
));

if (is_null($post) || in_array(null, $post)) {
    header("location:login.php");
    return; // missing fields (or failed filter)
} 

// pw is the password sent from the form 
$pw=$_POST['passwd'];
$name=$_POST['name'];

if($pw == 'testpass'){
    header("location:index.php");
} else {
    header("location:wrong.php");
}
?>
```

Is this a secure way to ensure the form is sent to the server and executed ONLY after the input values have been sanitized?

Also, the $name value i want to pass it to index.php file. I insert a code in the index.php as follow:

```
<?php echo $name ?>
```

But it's empty. Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: You neither output the values you got from user nor store them into a database. The only meaningful thing this code seems to do with user input is comparing `$_POST['passwd']` with 'test123' string; immediately after it the user will be redirected either to `index.php` or `wrong.php`. So, the question is: why do you need to sanitize something that will be thrown away soon?

Comment: As a sidenote, [session_register()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) `has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0`. In other words, its usage is not quite recommended.

Comment: a website was infected with code insertion, so I am being safe then be sorry later. Is it doing the job of sanitizing?

Comment: the only thing i know of that properly sanitizes it's SOAP

Comment: Ok I can remove the session_register() which was just an add on, but not required for this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `magic_quotes_gpc` should be disabled on most servers by now; however, do read [this article](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) to see other ways of disabling them.

Furthermore, you can use [`filter_input_array()`](https://www.php.net/filter_input_array) (PHP >= 5.2) for this purpose:

```
$post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, array(
    'name' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'pw' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
));

if (is_null($post) || in_array(null, $post)) {
    return; // missing fields (or failed filter)
}

// you can safely use $post['name'] and $post['pw'] here
```

Comment: so your code will sanitize the input values for any xss attack or any script insertion? I updated the code in my question, please let me know if it's good. Thanks

Comment: @Interfaith right, though you're missing the `session_register()` that you had previously.

Comment: raina77ow said session_register() was REMOVED with the new version of PHP, so i removed it.

Comment: Does this mean I have a lower version of PHP: Fatal error: Call to undefined function: filter_input_array() in checkpw.php on line 4

Comment: @Interfaith btw, questions are typically not updated with verbatim code from an answer; rather, if the answer was useful you should upvote it and wait for a few more answers based on your original question.

Comment: @Interfaith erhm, `filter_input_array()` only become a core component since 5.2

Answer (score 2):

You are issuing a `header( .. )`, that means that you are redirecting to another page and start all over.

You have 3 options:

- put your $name in the session.
- pass the $name in the header function, like  `header("location: index.php?name=$name");`
- do not redirect, but include the php file. In that case you do not need a session at all. Will be faster also, because you do not need a round trip to the browser.

As for sanitizing, for a start it will do. It depents what you later on will do with the data. I would suggest, if putting the data in a database to look in more detail what to do.

Comment: how do i add the $name in the header function to pass to index.php?

Comment: edited my post with a 3th option. I would go for not redirecting.

Comment: a website was infected with code insertion, so I am being safe then be sorry later. I am only comparing password and redirecting to another page based on user input. Is it doing the job of sanitizing?